# Needed updated Tumblr api implementation for android

Tags: android, tumblr, jumblr

I am working with some social media API .
I am successful in working with `Twitter` & `Facebook`

I also wanted to work on `Tumblr API` for posting directly through my android app.

I `googled` and found samples which are very much `out dated` and some doesn't works

I came across `Jumblr API` , I too tried to implement that , but `stucked` in some somewhere , for which I couldn't find the support online

Currently I am working with [this sample](https://github.com/RobertSzkutak/AndroidExamples/blob/master/TumblrExample/src/com/robertszkutak/androidexamples/tumblrexample/TumblrExampleActivity.java)    , but this is too outdated

So any one help me with the updated implementation of `Tumblr API` for android OR a good tutorial

Comment: You're sample didn't link - please edit.

Comment: edited  . please have a look

Comment: You should be using Jumblr only and try to resolve the issue that you found. As it is only official Java api for Tumblr.

Comment: any good tutorial for it ?